# sudo command using java not working

Tags: java, linux, sudo

I have this code to execute a command with and without using `sudo` option

```
String sudoScript = "sudo -u root -S ls /";
String script = "ls /";
try {
    System.out.println("===================================");
    System.out.println("command="+sudoScript);
    Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sudoScript);
            System.out.println("p2.waitFor()="+p1.waitFor());
    BufferedReader stdInput1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
    while ((sudoScript = stdInput1.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(script);
    }
    System.out.println("===================================");
    System.out.println("command="+script);
    Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script);
            System.out.println("p2.waitFor()="+p2.waitFor());
    BufferedReader stdInput2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
    while ((script = stdInput2.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(script);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this is the kind of output I get-

```
===================================
command=sudo -u root -S ls /
p2.waitFor()=1
===================================
command=ls /
p2.waitFor()=0
bin
boot
cgroup
data
dev
etc
home
home.save
lib
lost+found
media
mnt
null
opt
opt.save
proc
root
sbin
selinux
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
```

If you observe, I'm not able to get the same output using `sudo` command. Is there something I've missed here?

Comment: Did you grant permissions to use sudo to the user executing the script?

Comment: yes I do. It is working fine when I execute it in terminal as a command.

Comment: But does it ask you for the password? You can use the `NOPASSWD:` expression in sudoers to avoid it.

Comment: You are only dumping the stdout to the screen. Dump also stderr and the exit status of the process. `sudo` may be giving an error message that you are not seeing.

Comment: @Joni I've included everything in my output here.

Comment: Exit status 1 confirms that `sudo` is failing with an error. Try dumping also the stderr on the console (`p1.getErrorStream()`)

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays most distros have sudo configured to require tty to execute.

try (within /etc/sudoers):

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

or

```
Defaults!/path/to/program !requiretty
```

You need to make sure sudo does not require a password for that user for that particular command (e.g. `ls /`) or you need to supply it to `sudo`.

UPDATE: btw, it is a good idea to read stderr as well so we don't have to guess what is wrong with command execution

Comment: this command doesn't work for me. I get `command not found` error

Comment: @user1649068, edited answer to specify this is `sudoers` directive.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to pipe in a password to the sudo command.

Comment: password is not what I'm worried about. mine doesn't ask for one.

Answer (score 0):

The command `sudo -u root -S ls /` prompts for the user password.

Something like `echo '[password]' | sudo -u root -S ls /` might do the trick.

Note:
This requires hard-coding the password.  Which is probably not the best idea.

EDIT:
According to `man sudo`, the `-u root` option is unnecessary. Running `sudo -S ls /` will have the same effect.

Comment: java will execute it as a plain `echo` command and display output as `[password] | sudo -u root -S ls /`

Comment: @user1649068  I've edited the command.  Like that it works on my machine (at the command prompt).